# OAuth access for R

Tags: r, oauth

I'm trying to use R to grab some web data that requires OAuth authentication. Searching on CRAN and RSeek.org for info on OAuth + R provides nothing. Any tips for accessing RESTful APIs with R using OAuth?

I'm considering using some Python/Perl/Ruby to grab the data, save it to a text file, then work on it with R. I'd prefer to stay totally in R, but it seems like OAuth is a barrier.

Comment: You might also considering using Python to break through OAuth, then calling R from Python via RPy2 or PypeR

Comment: Hmmm.. how about calling Python from R? Since I want to do most of my analysis in R it seems to make sense to wrap only the data retrieval bits in Python then pass back an object of some kind to R.

Comment: @brandon, nope. But Jeff Gentry has been wanting a solution for twitter. My immediate use case was for pulling fantasy football data through Yahoo's API.

Comment: While not directly into R, I know of a few companies that are using php-oauth -> mysql -> R. For social media / sentiment analysis.

Comment: Brandon that sounds like a great answer. Can you flesh it out a tad and put it as an answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out Jeff Gentry from TwitteR wrote his own OAuth R library.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROAuth/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Best approach now appears to be to use `httr` (https://github.com/r-lib/httr)

Answer (score 2):

One option I stumbled on is called [OAuth Proxy](http://mojodna.net/2009/08/21/exploring-oauth-protected-apis.html) and it slips the OAuth headers in using a proxy. This is an interesting kludge.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible, assuming you have access to the required crypto functions in R, you can implement OAuth completely as HTTP requests without any lib support etc.

While writing a complete oauth lib might be asking too much, if you just need a quick and dirty way to pull down data, it shouldn't be too difficult to hand craft the few functions you need to complete an oauth request.

Also, while R may not have an oauth lib, most of the difficult part of oauth is in the interaction between servers, not in creating the tokens/requests, so you should be able to look at another language's implementation and port the required logic to R.  I would suggest looking at a simple lib from http://oauth.net/code/ for a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this with the RCurl library as well. The main thing is that you parse the access_tokens and authorization verifications correctly.  But I've managed to pull lots of data off of facebook with R via getURL.