# tweeting out of R console

Tags: r, twitter

I tried to tweet from my R Console using this code

```
    library("RCurl")
opts <- curlOptions(header = FALSE, 
                    userpwd = "username:password", netrc = FALSE)

tweet <- function(status){
  method <- "http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml?status="
  encoded_status <- URLencode(status)
  request <- paste(method, encoded_status, sep = "")
  postForm(request,.opts = opts)
}

tweet("This tweet comes from R! #rstats")
```

but get this error: raw(0)
Warnmeldung:
In postForm(request, .opts = optss) : No inputs passed to form.

Can somenone help me on this? Found the code on http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/06/tweeting-from-r.html

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252694/using-r-to-send-tweets?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter disabled the basic authentication scheme in 2010. This don´t work anymore. You have to use the OAuth2-Authentification.

The easiest way here is the twitteR-Package available on CRAN.

First step: Authentification:

```
consumer_key <- "yourcredentials"
consumer_secret <- "yourcredentials"
access_token <- "yourcredentials"
access_secret <- "yourcredentials"
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
```

You have to Set-up an API-APP on Twitter to get the Keys: https://apps.twitter.com/

After this step it´s the same as in your question:

```
tweet("Hello World")
```

Daily limit are 2400 tweets.