# How to send tweets in R?

Tags: r, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, rcurl

Possibly a duplicate question with [Using R to send tweets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252694/using-r-to-send-tweets) but unfortunatly it provides only answers on how to use OAuth for R.

I have installed the `TwitteR` package from Jeff Gentry and I'm able to authenticate myself using Oauth, but from what I see in the documentation there are functions to manipulate Twitter direct messages (`dmSend` and `dmGet` ) but I cannot find anything to send tweets.

```
  > consumer_key <- "xxx"
  > consumer_secret <- "zzz"
  > access_token <- "aaa"
  > access_secret <- "bbb"
  > setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
  [1] "Using direct authentication"
```

Now that I'm authenticate, how can I use `RCurl` to submit a valid HTML form and send tweets ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `twitteR` package:

```
updateStatus("Tweet goes here.")
```

Alternate `httr` way:

```
# assign keys and secrets
api_key <- "a"
api_secret <- "b"
access_token <- "c"
access_token_secret <- "d"

# authenticate with httr
oauth_endpoints("twitter")
myapp <- oauth_app("twitter", key = api_key, secret = api_secret)
twitter_token <- oauth1.0_token(oauth_endpoints("twitter"), myapp)

tweet <- "Tweet goes here."
tweet <- gsub(" ","%20", tweet)

httr::POST(
  url = paste0("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=", tweet, "&display_coordinates=false"),
  config(token = twitter_token)
)
```

Comment: Tweet status is excatly what I was looking for, thank you